# JS: window.scroll(x,y) pointing to another frame will not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome, scroll

So,I have two iframes, one which is designated as "showframe" and represents a huge map:

```
<iframe src="map.xhtml" width="100%" height="400" name="showframe
```

The other one contains list of all locations, which uses JS to center the first iframe on given coordinates on that map:

```
<a class="locind" href="javascript:window.scroll(630,820);" target ="showframe"> Location A</a>
```

The point is, it works perfectly in FireFox, however, chrome doesn't seem to be able to detect targeted frame, and centers itself instead. I googled and searched around, and found this:

```
<script>  
    function myScroll(id, x, y) {document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.scroll(x, y);
    }  
</script>  

<a class="locind" href="javascript:myScroll('showframe', 630,820);" >Hotel Bosna</a>
```

But this doesn't do anything when I click on the link, and I' not sure why... Anyway, if you can find the problem with the second code, or have a better solution, please, enlighten me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
<a class="locind" href="#" onclick="window.showframe.scrollTo(630,820); return false" > Location A</a>
```

or

```
<a class="locind" href="#" onclick="parent.showframe.scrollTo(630,820); return false" > Location A</a>
```

assuming

```
<iframe name="showframe"
```

If you have id="showframe" please try

```
parent.document.getElementById('showframe').contentWindow.scrollTo(..)
```

Comment: Tried it, and it only centered the screen of the same iframe where link is located.

Comment: Updated answer. I did not notice you are scrolling an IFRAME from another iframe.

Comment: Thank you very much, parent.showframe.scrollTo worked just fine. thanks again

Comment: Great. Feel free to vote it up too. I am getting too many non-voted accepted answers :(

Comment: Can it be down between sibling frames?

Comment: The frames in the question are sibling frames

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML pages we're talking about are both local pages with "file://" URLs, then Chrome won't let one page mess with another because it considers them to be from distinct domains (regardless of the URL path).

If you launch Chrome with the argument "--allow-file-access-from-files" then it'll allow such interactions.

Comment: tried that as well, but it centers the main screen, not the frame. Is there anyway, I can use this in combination with target?